# Get Friendlist using JSSDK after Page like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen many fanpages getting my friendlist after I like their page, without any permission dialog screen, I've tried alot to do it but always got "exception token required".

So is it possible to get users friends list after they like our page??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, I am using underscore.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) with no conflict:

```
var UnderScore = _.noConflict();
```

This query gets friends for `me()`, which is currently logged in Facebook user. You can replace `me()` with a Facebook user id.

Code to get friends:

```
    var friends = {handles:[],ids:[],names:[]};
    var q = 'select username, uid, name from user where '+
      'uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())';
    var r=FB.Data.query(q);
    r.wait(function(rows){
      if (UnderScore.isArray(rows) && (rows.length>0)) {
        UnderScore.each(rows,function(i){
          if (i.username && !UnderScore.isNull(i.username)) {
            friends.handles.push(i.username.toString().toLowerCase());
            if (i.name && !UnderScore.isNull(i.name)) {
              friends.names[i.username.toString().toLowerCase()] = i.name
            }
          }
          if (i.uid && !UnderScore.isNull(i.uid)) {
            friends.ids.push(i.uid.toString().toLowerCase());
            if (i.name && !UnderScore.isNull(i.name)) {
              friends.names[i.uid.toString().toLowerCase()] = i.name
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

After that code runs, which will be an asynchronous event, the variable `friends` will be populated with ids, names, and handles for Facebook friends.

Answer (score 0):

No this is **not** possible. You need the current user id with sufficient permissions to get the user's friends' list, and Facebook won't share the user's id just by him liking your page.

I'm not sure how *these* pages you are talking about are doing it, maybe using the old deprecated FBML, but again...*I don't think this is possible without user authorization*.